# Execute JavaScript Function via a href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

I am having a "duh" moment in which I am trying to execute a JavaScript function via an `a` `href`.

```
<a href="javascript:test()">Open New Form</a>
```

The function is stored in an external JavaScript file. If I have it inline with my function within `<script>` tags and the a `href` after it, it works.

What is the best method to execute a JavaScript function stored in another file?

Comment: Did you add the file using `<script src="/path/to/file.js"></script>` ? If so, you can call functions from there like they were in the same file.

Comment: Yes, which is odd. I may try to use jQuery's click

Comment: Probably you can use ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(test,'scriptname');

Comment: Agreed. Nothing showing up except that it is undefined. Any good articles on how to do this in jQuery?

Comment: Wait. I am loading the JavaScript files via the XML Viewer Web Part so while they show as included, it is post DOM load. Should that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was tied to caching as I had made updates to my JavaScript file but it wasn't showing. I resolved this, and then my core issue by using the following jQuery in my JavaScript file to call the function on click:

```
    $('#commentlink').click(function () {
    addComment();
});
```

This is called in the HTML like this:

```
<a class="pointer" id="commentlink" onclick="javascript:OpenPopUpPage();">Add Comment</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not linking to another page, try using the `<button>` element:

`<button onclick="test()">Open a New Form</button>`

Also, make sure your JavaScript file is properly loading on the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you use

`<a href="javascript:test()">Open New Form</a>`

and keep "test" function outside the page then also it will work as long as you are giving the reference of that javascript in your page like `<script src="path"></script>`

As you wanted the onclick function of the element so its good/best to use

```
<a onclick="test()"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<a href="javascript:" onclick="test()">Open New Form</a>
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.